# Load JSON by URI using inline JSON in Polymer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polymer, web-component

I am making a d3.js map component with Polymer. The topology data needs to be loaded from a json file and since I don't want the component to be dependent on a URL/URI, I am using inline JSON instead of loading it using AJAX:

```
<polymer-element name="map-us">
    <template>


        <script id="topodata" type="application/json" src="data/us.json"></script> 

        /* ... more stuff ... */

    </template>


    <script>

        Polymer('map-us', {


            ready: function() {

                /* 
                This  works in regular HTML/JQuery:

                var x = JSON.parse($('#myJson').html());
                console.log(x.arcs);

                */

                var x = JSON.parse(this.$.topodata.html());
                console.log(x.arcs);

        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

But obviously topdata element doesn't have the method html().

Is it the right thing to do? 
and how vulcanize deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to inline JSON file. Polymer's resolvePath function is useful here to make sure the relative path to JSON file is always correct regardless of where the component is included:

```
this.topojsonURI = 'data/us.json';

/* d3.json basically just makes the json call */

d3.json(this.resolvePath(this.topojsonURI), function() {
  /* code rendering the map */
}
```

Info about resolvePath [here](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#resolvepath).

UPDATE (Polymer 1.0):

The function name has been changed to `resolveUrl`: [1.0 API Docs](http://polymer.github.io/polymer/)

Answer (score 1):

You're not depending on an external resource but it's still in a separate file. I'd use core-ajax to load it:

```
<core-ajax id="topodata" auto url="data/us.json" handleAs="json"
           response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
...

responseChanged: function() {
  //this.response is your JSON
}
```

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax

Comment: Thanks Eric, (do you mean url="data/us.json" instead of src)? core-ajax was my first idea but then shouldn't I provide an absolute URL for the url?   I was using regular ajax before but data/us.json seems to be considered relative to the page which has the component in it and not the component definition directory which has data/us.json in it.

Comment: Yep, I meant `url`. The path can be whatever you want, as long as your  web server resolves to the correct location of that data file.